# Linq and group by clause

Tags: linq

I am curious what the *x* is for in a a linq group by clause: *group **x** by* ...

The x can be replaced by an 1:

```
       var query = from box in c.Boxes
                    join item in c.Items on box equals item.Box
                    group 1 by new { BoxId = box.BoxId, item.ItemType.ItemTypeId } into g
                    select new {  g.Key.BoxId, g.Key.ItemTypeId, Count = g.Count() };
```

Does anybody have a sample where the x (or wathever local variable you chose in the group by )  is really of some value?

I mean

```
var query2 =  from box in c.Boxes
                              group box by box.BoxId into q
                              select q.Key;
```

can be replaced by

```
var query2 =  from box in c.Boxes
                              group 1 by box.BoxId into q
                              select q.Key;
```

Comment: You can use expression instead of `x`.

Comment: x is what is aggregated by the group by. So replacing it with 1 doesnt make much sense undless you need an IEnumerable<int> full of 1s for each group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In group x by... the x is what gets aggregated.

So you could write something like

```
var childrenByAge = from child in class
                    group getName(child) by child.Age;
```

This gives you a grouping containing names of children for each age.

Here is a simple example where you can test the difference easily:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var grouping = from c in "Hello World!"
                       group c by  c;  // Replace 'group c by' with 'group 1 by'
                                       // and compare results


        foreach (var group in grouping)
        {
            Console.Write("KEY:  {0} VALUES :", group.Key);
            foreach (var value in group)
                Console.Write(" {0}", value);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the expression that determines what will go in the output of the `group by` clause.

You are actually not inspecting the whole output, but only the `Keys`, which are the same in the examples above, because the grouping is done by the same thing (`box.BoxId`).

However, replace the last line:

```
select q.Key;
```

with

```
select q;
```

You will notice that:

- the `group 1 by ...` query will return an `IGrouping<int, int>` which will have all values set to 1
- the `group box by ...` query will return an `IGrouping<int, Box>`, which will have all the boxId keys and, for each of them, the corresponding `Box` objects with respect to the grouping criteria.